# Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I already posted this question but I gave it a try I'm not sure if I'm on the right track:

Make a util class with three methods. First method's name is add, that returns the result by adding two numbers.

Second method's name is multiply, that returns the result by multiplying two numbers.

Third's method name is division that returns a result by dividing first parameter by second parameter. How would I do this part?

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Util {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        int result = a + b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int res = add(5, 2);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);
    }
    public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
        int result = a * b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int res = multiply(5, 2);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to create a class with three methods?
I see one class with two main method and two other methods..

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {` is used as an entry point  by jvm so it would be confused by 2 main and also you cant have 2 method  with same name and args so use one main method

Comment: class must not have two `main` method

Comment: How would I correct it?

Comment: use [one main](http://ideone.com/2hcQvj) method to call both add,multiply methods

Comment: oh oops I get it thanks! How would I do this: Third's method name is division that returns a result by dividing first parameter by second parameter. How would I do this part?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are confusing is the multiple main methods. You should only have 1 entry point (main) in your code, the rest of your util class is correct.

```
public class Util {
    public static int add(int a, int b){

        int result = a + b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

    return result;
    }

    public static int multiply(int a, int b){

    int result = a * b;
    System.out.println("result = " + result);

    return result;
    }

    public static int divide(int a, int b){

        int result = a / b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

        return result;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] aValues = {1,2,3,4}; 
        int[] bValyes = {4,3,2,1}; 
         for (int i = 0; i < aValues.length; i++) {
            int a = aValues[i];
            int b = bBalues[i];

            int res = multiply(a, b);
            System.out.println("res = " + res);

            res = add(a, b);
            System.out.println("res = " + res);

            res = divide(a, b);
            System.out.println("res = " + res);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more quick question. If I wanted to call a method from this class called main and print the results 6 times for each method call, am I on the right track?   public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args, int b) {
  
  Util.main(args);

Comment: You don't need a separate class. If you want your main in a different class that is fine, but delete the one from the above util class as it is no longer needed.

Basically for how ever many times you want to call each method, you would just call them. For example if you have int[] aValues = {1,2,3,4}; int[] bValyes = {4,3,2,1}; and iterated over those passing to each method, that is valid.

Comment: So how would I do it?

Comment: I edited the example I gave with exactly what I commented which leads me to believe you are in way over your head. You need to do some basic reading on programming theory and principles as this is programming 101.